# Does my server's port 8080 have to be open when connecting to a remote 8080 port?

Tags: php, port, fsockopen

I'm trying to use [fsockopen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) to connect from my apache server to a remote API server. The **remote** server script I need to connect to runs on port 8080.

The following keeps returning a `101 connection timed out` error:

```
$fp = fsockopen('remote.example.com', '8080', $errno, $errstr, 10);
```

Do I need to open port 8080 on **my** server in order to connect to that port on the remote server?

And if so, is there any way to do that using e.g. `.htaccess`, or would I have to modify httpd.conf for that?

Thanks!

ADDED

Thanks everybody for the replies. You were all correct, but I can only accept 1 answer, so I accepted the first one.

If anyone is interested: this is on a Wiredtree server and after emailing support, they said that they have that disabled by default for security reasons (also cURL), but they can enable it upon request. I'm sure that once they do, this problem will be solved.

Thought I'd post this in case anyone else is experiencing the same problem in the future.

Comment: NO, local port is choosed randomly

Comment: No. For example, you're constantly browsing websites YET you didn't have to open your port 80 for it to work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, all ports are open going *outwards* unless explicitly blocked.  I think there's something else at play here.  Is the remote API server running?  Is it indeed running on port 8080 and can you check?  Have you tried to connect using telnet to port 8080?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It was my server after all, I've updated my OP.

Answer (score 1):

No, You need not. When you connect to another server, your server is being the client, and the client's port number is chosen from the dynamic port range.

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not have to open your server's 8080 port. Are you in a corporate or government setting where you might be sitting behind a proxy server? If so you might not be able to reach that destination without going through the proxy.

Comment: I'm not behind a proxy - it's a normal Apache server. How could I check if port 8080 is open for outbound traffic?